# jQuery/JavaScript for-Loop and .append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started yesterday with jQuery and JavaScript and run into an error.

All I want is to place Ads randomly after an H1-Tag (so let's say there are 10 H1 on a page dived by 2 = 5 AdPosition) now add 5 AdBlocks after a randomly choosen H1.

Sounds pretty easy but I cant achieve this...: / because jQuery or myCode only paste one AdBlock.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/byt3w4rri0r/eCBCK/ - working!

---

MyHTML:

```
<body>
<div id="content-inner">
    <h1 class="headline">Headline</h1>
    <h1 class="headline">Headline</h1>
    <h1 class="headline">Headline</h1>
    <h1 class="headline">Headline</h1>
    <h1 class="headline">Headline</h1>
    <h1 class="headline">Headline</h1>
    <h1 class="headline">Headline</h1>
    <h1 class="headline">Headline</h1>
    <h1 class="headline">Headline</h1>
    <h1 class="headline">Headline</h1>
</div>
</body>​
```

---

MyJQUERY/JavaScript:

```
//count H1
var countH1 = parseFloat($("#content-inner h1").length)-1; //-1 because 0 is also a number!

//how often the ads should be displayed
var ad_count = Math.round(countH1 / 2);

//random helper
var min = 0;
var max = countH1;

//random position
for (counter = 0; counter < ad_count; counter++){
    var random_position = Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);

    console.log("Random_Position:", random_position);

    // paste google-code

    if ($(".headline").hasClass('advertised') == true) {
        random_position++;

        console.log('already advertised!')

        if (random_position > countH1) {
            random_position--;
            }
    } else {
        $('h1:eq('+random_position+')').append('<div class="google_ad1"></div>');
        $('h1.headline').addClass('advertised');
        }
}

console.log("CountH1 -1, because 0=1, 1=2,....", countH1);
console.log(werbung_anzahl);
console.log(zufall_position);
console.log(counter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this line

```
if ($(".headline").hasClass('advertised') == true)
```

you are checking if any(!) of the .headline elements has already been advertised. And after the first step there is always one .headline that has been advertised, so this comparison will be true.

What you wanted to do: Check if the .headline with the current index has been advertised

```
if ($(".headline").eq(random_position).hasClass('advertised') == true)
```

On top of this, you are adding the class "advertised" to all(!) your h1.headline elements. This is what you wanted to do instead

```
$('h1.headline').eq(random_position).addClass('advertised');
```

EDIT: This is the full changed for loop from the latest fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/eCBCK/19

```
for (counter = 0; counter < ad_count; counter++){
    var random_position = Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);

    console.log("Random_Position:", random_position);

    // paste google-code

    if ($(".headline").eq(random_position).hasClass('advertised') == true) {
        counter--;

        console.log('already advertised!')


    } else {
        $('h1:eq('+random_position+')').append('<div class="google_ad1"></div>');
        $('h1.headline').eq(random_position).addClass('advertised');
        }
}
```

Comment: hi when i paste your codesnippet to my jsFiddle nothing happens... but when i paste it like:

   if ($(".headline").eq('+random_position+').hasClass('advertised') == true)

it generates 3 adblock after oneH1 (not everyone)

Comment: I have updated the fiddle exactly as mentioned above and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/eCBCK/15/

Comment: If you update the fiddle to this: http://jsfiddle.net/eCBCK/19/ it will always show 5 ads for 10 headlines

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if i'm wrong, but you are adding the class "advertised" to all of your h1 elements, this means that on the second loop you are testing if advertised has already been added to the h1, which will now always be true and no more adds are appened

Comment: hi, yes thats true i will try to figure out whats wrong... thx for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's chaining feature:

```
$('h1:eq('+random_position+')').append('<div class="google_ad1"></div>').addClass('advertised');
```

This will only add the `advertised` class to the H1 that you just appended to.

Comment: hi, thx for your answer this is the solution for the hint given to my by "mark walters"! But now it happens that sometimes 2 ad-boxes appear after an H1...